# Create a list from enum

Tags: swiftui

I'd like to be able to create a `List` from an `enum` that conforms to `CaseIterable` and `CustomStringConvertible` e.g.

```swift
public enum HairColor: Int, Codable, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .black:
            return "Black"
        case .blond:
            return "Blond"
        case .brown:
            return "Brown"
        case .red:
            return "Red"
        case .grey:
            return "Gray"
        case .bald:
            return "Bald"
        }
    }
    case blond, brown, black, red, grey, bald
}
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SwiftUIHelpers.enumToList(HairColor)
    }
}
```

This is the approach I've tried but I get the error: "Cannot convert value of type 'Text' to closure result type '_"

```swift
struct SwiftUIHelpers {
    static func enumToList<T: CaseIterable, RandomAccessCollection>(_ a: T) -> some View {
        List {
            ForEach(a, id: \.rawValue) { (o: CustomStringConvertible) in
                Text(o.description)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What is the error on my ways?!?

Answer (score 1):

Here is working solution. Tested with Xcode 11.4 / iOS 13.4.

```
struct SwiftUIHelpers {
    static func enumToList<T: CaseIterable>(_ t: T.Type) -> some View 
           where T.AllCases: RandomAccessCollection, T: Hashable & CustomStringConvertible {
        List {
            ForEach(t.self.allCases, id: \.self) { o in
                Text(o.description)
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        SwiftUIHelpers.enumToList(HairColor.self)
    }
}

public enum HairColor: Int, Codable, Hashable, CaseIterable, CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        switch self {
        case .black:
            return "Black"
        case .blond:
            return "Blond"
        case .brown:
            return "Brown"
        case .red:
            return "Red"
        case .grey:
            return "Gray"
        case .bald:
            return "Bald"
        }
    }
    case blond, brown, black, red, grey, bald
}
```

**Update:** Having played with this more I've found that the following extension can be much more helpful

```
extension CaseIterable where Self.AllCases: RandomAccessCollection, Self: Hashable & CustomStringConvertible {
    static func toForEach() -> some View  {
        ForEach(Self.allCases, id: \.self) { o in
            Text(o.description).tag(o)
        }
    }
}
```

because gives wider reuse possibility, like

```
List { HairColor.toForEach() }
```

and this

```
Form { HairColor.toForEach() }
```

and

[image: demo]

```
struct DemoHairColorPicker: View {
    @State private var hairColor: HairColor = .red
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Text("Selected: \(hairColor.description)")
            Picker(selection: $hairColor, label: Text("Hair")) { HairColor.toForEach() }
        }
    }
}
```

and of course in any stack `VStack { HairColor.toForEach() }`

Comment: This is definitely moving closer, thank you! The List can't id the elements with `ForEach(t.self.allCases, id: \.self)`, do you have an idea of how to get `ForEach(t.self.allCases, id: \.rawValue)` to compile?

Comment: @Norman, the provided code in answer compiled & tested in run-time as noted. Just check if you adapt it accurately.

Comment: first of all thank you for your help on this. While the solution you provided compiles and even displays correctly, it doesn't provide a mechanism for the `List` to differentiate each of the elements because of the use of `id: \.self`. When you actually use the code you suggest e.g. in a `Form` `Picker` the item chosen is not registered because of this issue. To have a functional `List` each element in it was be identifiable, thus the need to use `id: \.rawValue`.

Comment: I've posted code at https://gist.github.com/nbasham/58802c851a8269c818707fc63f29cb54 to demonstrate the issue with the proposed solution. Notice that the picker does not retain the selected value when using the updated extension.

Answer (score 0):

Not really an answer to all parts of your question - only the first part - but offered here as an alternative...

Might be worth considering the use of @EnvironmentObject for a @Published property? I used this to populate a sidebar style menu for a macOS target.

**Step 1:**

Use your enum. My enum is written a little differently to yours but I thought to leave it that way because it provides an alternate construction... but with the same outcome.

(Conforming to `CaseIterable` here allows us to use the `.allCases` method in Step 2.)

```
enum HairColor: Int, CaseIterable {

    case blond = 0, brown, black, red, grey, none

    var description: String {

        switch self {

        case .blond: return "Blond"
        case .brown: return "Brown"
        case .black: return "Black"
        case .red:   return "Red"
        case .grey:  return "Grey"
        case .none:  return "Bald"
        }
    }
}
```

**Step 2:**

Create a struct for your model and include a static property that maps all cases of your HairColor enum.

(Conforming to `Identifiable` here allows us to use the cleaner `ForEach` syntax in Step 4 - that is - use `ForEach(appData.hairColors)` in lieu of `ForEach(appData.hairColors, id: \.id)`).

```
import SwiftUI

struct Hair: Codable, Hashable, Identifiable {

    var id: Int
    var name: String

    init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }

    static var colors: [Hair] {
        return HairColor.allCases.map({ Hair(id: $0.rawValue, name: $0.description ) })
    }
}
```

**Step 3:**

Create a class that conforms to ObservableObject and that contains a @Published wrapped property to allow you to broadcast your HairColor via @EnvironmentObject.

```
import Combine // <- don't forget this framework import!
import SwiftUI

final class AppData: ObservableObject {

    @Published var hairColors = Hair.colors
}
```

**Step 4:**

Use in a `View`.

```
struct HairList: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var appData: AppData

    @State var selectedHair: Hair?

    var body: some View {

        VStack(alignment: .leading) {

            Text("Select...")
                .font(.headline)

            List(selection: $selectedHair) {

                ForEach(appData.hairColors) { hairColor in

                    Text(hairColor.name).tag(hairColor)
                }
            }
            .listStyle(SidebarListStyle())
        }
        .frame(minWidth: 100, maxWidth: 150)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

**Step 5:**

Remember to inject the environment object into the preview to make the preview usable.

```
struct HairList_Previews: PreviewProvider {

    static var previews: some View {

        HairList(selectedHair: .constant(AppData().hairColors[1]))
            .environmentObject(AppData())
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for such a thoughtful and well documented solution! While it doesn't solve my current dilemma it gives me a lot to think about e.g. wrapping the enum cases in an identifiable wrapper, AND introduced me to SidebarListStyle, I'll file that away if do some Mac work. Thank you again, your answer is notably clearly presented.